How to set QTableWidget select only mouse click
I want to select a row in QTableWidget by clicking on it, but when my row contains a cellWidget, the selection change event will be triggered when there is no click (for example: the mouse moves in the Table).
Should I receive the ItemClicked signal myself to handle it? Selected? Or is there any other better way?
Selection changes triggered by mouse movement do occur, When the mouse slides vertically over the buttons in each row (without click)
This is part of my minimal reproducible example:
    table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
    table->setSelectionBehavior(QTableWidget::SelectRows);
    table->setSelectionMode(QTableWidget::SingleSelection);
    table->setEditTriggers(QTableWidget::NoEditTriggers);
    table->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    table->setMouseTracking(true);

    table->setColumnCount(3);
    table->setRowCount(5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        table->setItem(i, 0, new QTableWidgetItem{QString::number(i)});
        table->setItem(i, 1, new QTableWidgetItem{"Example"});
        table->setItem(i, 2, new QTableWidgetItem{});

        auto btn = new QPushButton{"Button", table};
        table->setCellWidget(i, 2, btn);
    }

// My connect
connect(table, &QTableWidget::itemSelectionChanged, this, &MyClass::myHandle);
//...



Your question is unclear. There is no selection change when the mouse moves, unless you implemented it. Also, what is bracketTableWgt? Please clarify your problem and provide a proper [mre].
